# Calling a Stored Procedure every n seconds

Tags: c#, .net, sql, multithreading, timer

I don't have much experience with multi threading so I am wondering how to refresh my Data Grid View every, for example, two seconds.

Basically, when the user is on a certain tab, and they have selected 'Currently Importing', it should call a method GetNotImportedFiles() every n seconds, the method then calls the SP and binds the DataSet.

Obviously, I need a timer which will do this every n seconds but I need it to execute the method as a background worker but communicate with the UI thread to update the DataGridView.

If you need any code, please ask.

UPDATE: I have implemented a timer but it never seems to hit the method for timerTick?

In my designer I have the code:

```
this.refreshTimer.Interval = 1000;
this.refreshTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.refreshTimer_Tick);
```

My understanding is that refreshTimer_Click should be called every 1 second. But I have a breakpoint in the code that is never hit?

```
private void refreshTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (searchComboBox.Text.Equals("Currently Importing"))
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet temp = EngineBllUtility.GetNotImportedFiles(connectionString);
                if (temp != null)
                    importFileGridView.DataSource = temp.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you create an event that you will raise everytime progress has changed?

Comment: Does SP mean Stored Procedure? You should probably clarify that somewhere (maybe in the title at least)

Comment: @bojanskr Because progress will change very quickly as there could be a number of imports running simultaneously as web users can do it through the web.

Comment: Eurgh, didn't set it to enabled. Sorry guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mske use of  : [Timer in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WorkingwithTimerControlinCSharp11302005054911AM/WorkingwithTimerControlinCSharp.aspx) which allow to query data after every timer tick...you can visite link for more detail about timer.

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer(500);
timer1.Interval = 5000;
timer1.Enabled = true;
timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler (OnTimerEvent);

Write the event handler

This event will be executed after every 5 secs.

public static void OnTimerEvent(object source, EventArgs e)
{
m_streamWriter.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
m_streamWriter.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that there are different Timer classes in the .NET Framework. System.Windows.Forms.Timer is a control for WinForm applications and does not run in a separate thread and therefore blocks the UI thread if the operation takes some time. System.Threading.Timer is used for multi-threading operations.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) to start the operation every n seconds and a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for the async call to the SP. Using only the Timer control does not create a background thread operation. This is where the BackgroundWorker comes in. It allows very easy access to a background thread without the need of complex synchronization.